# Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

In Angular, I switched from version 12 to version 14. Everything is working perfectly.

My issue is that I have a warning that bothers me, but I don't know how to resolve the issue?

```
./src/styles.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6]
.rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6]
.rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6]
.rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6]
.rules[1].use[1]!./src/styles.scss 
- Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(12061:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKN5P.png)

I also provide you with the package.json file in case it can help:

```
{
    "name": "Golden",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --open",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.22",
        "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/localize": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^11.0.3",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
        "@ngneat/transloco": "^3.1.1",
        "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.2",
        "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.7.2",
        "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.2",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.0.1",
        "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^11.2.0-alpha.4",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typeface-nunito": "^1.1.13",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.13",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "^14.2.13",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^14.2.13",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^14.2.13",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^14.2.13",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^14.2.13",
        "@angular/cli": "^14.2.13",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^14.3.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.9.1",
        "@types/node": "^12.20.37",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.9.0",
        "karma": "^6.3.9",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
        "typescript": "~4.6.4"
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and your time with my issue.

Comment: how much do you know about CSS flexbox? that's what the warning is about, well, probably align-items or align-self or justify-content or justify-self - not sure why it's complaining, I see no compatibility issues with using start vs flex-start (unless you use a REALLY old browser) - but flex-start is considered the same as start if you're not in a flex layout in some cases - best read up on it yourself

Comment: Thank you very much, it's solved the problem was with `start vs flex-start `